# SpringApplicationBuilder for specified profile over -Dspring.profile.active=local

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a integrationTest which needs to spin to applications. One at 8181 and 8185 both application needs to behave exactly the same but only difference is to listen on different ports.

I give -Dspring.profile.active=local for 8181 server and for other server I do

```
applicationContext = new SpringApplicationBuilder(springConfigs)
                        .profiles("abc")
                        .run();
```

But looks like even though I am specifying abc as a profile, other server starts with local profile - hence port 8181.

If I don't specify -Dspring.profile.active=local and use ActiveProfile then all works fine but since I cannot change -Dspring.profile.active=local piece I have to come up with alternate route. Is it possible to force SpringApplicationBuilder to use profile I specify?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Based on the order of precedence for spring boot properties give [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config) command line is among the top. But before that is `@TestPropertySource` and `SpringBootTest#properties`. The latter takes in an array of strings of form `key=value`.